# Postgresql COPY and \copy function

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, import, pgadmin

I would like to import a local csv file into a table on a db in the cloud.  I know this is a recurring issue for users, but I have not found a clear, concise answer for my situation, which I believe to be common.

My question: How do I use the correct COPY or \copy command? (I have zero psql experience) How do I format the location of the file I want to import?

My situation: I only have pgAdmin on my local Windows computer, from which I am running the sql code. The db I am connected to is in the cloud. I am not a superuser, but have write permissions to the table I'm attempting to add data to.

Answer (score 1):

Use the psql command line client

Change to the directory where the file is located

The command should be something like:

`PGHOST=hostname PGDATABASE=dbname psql -c "\copy tableName from 'file.csv' with (format csv)"`

You might need to set PGUSER and PGPASSWORD variables too

Docs are here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Where is the command line client? I'm using the latest pgAdmin 4 V2.1

Comment: @otterdog2000 I don't know about pgAdmin 4. It used to come with pgAdmin III

Comment: I found it, thanks. I typed psql in my explorer search and the sql shell came up. I don't think I had it with my pgAdmin III install.